# ../src/main.c:16:17: error: 'free' redeclared as different kind of symbol (Boolean)

Tags: c, boolean, redeclare

I have a boolean free defined as

```
bool inbetween, free, lunch;
```

The only other times I use the boolean are here

```
//get time info
memset(period, 0, sizeof(period));
free = false;
inbetween = false;
lunch = false;
```

(I declare it true in a couple of if statements)
And here:

```
if(free){
  for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
    period[i] = FREE[i];      
  }
}
if(lunch){
  for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
    period[i] = Lunch[i];      
  }
}
if(inbetween){
  for(int i=0;i<=8;i++){
    period[i] = Inbetween[i];      
  }
}
```

I use all 3 booleans the same amount of times, yet I'm only getting this error with free

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 3):

`free` is a library function that is used to free memory.  I recommend that you **not** use `free` as a variable name.